# Can an auto retopology model be rigged and unwrapped?

Tags: modeling, uv, sculpting, retopology

Can this model rigged and uv unwrapped? I used auto retopology plugin because I have no time to manual retopology. I need to import this character to Unreal engine.

[image: 3D Model]

Comment: the topology looks much too dense, you should reduce again

Comment: Well, any model can be rigged and uv unwrapped, and that one's in a reasonable T pose with reasonable topology, so yes.  Although, as @moonboots says, the mesh is pretty dense for a game character, so I second their suggestion to simplify the mesh further first.